# How to find the Fuschian group associated with a region of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quotient-spaces, conformal-geometry

Any connected open set in the complex plane (except for the plane and punctured plane) is [covered conformally by the unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610132/what-can-the-disk-conformally-cover). This in turn means that it is conformally covered by the hyperbolic plane (since the disk and hyperbolic plane are conformally equivalent).

For a given region $U$ in the complex plane that satisfies this criteria, let $q : H^2 \to U$ be the that covering map. He can then form a quotient of the hyperbolic plane as following

$$H_U = H^2/\{(a,b):p(a) = p(b)\}$$

That is, we identify points that are sent to same place by $p$. This will be a hyperbolic surface, and therefore will have a [Fuchsian model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_model). This Fuschian model will have an associated [Fuchsian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group) $\Gamma$.

---

So my question is starting with a region $U$, how do you find the group $\Gamma$?

EDIT: If I understand the idea of Fuschsian groups correctly, my question boils down to finding a group of conformal maps that "doesn't affect" the hyperbolic plane/unit disk. Namely, $g \in \Gamma$ iff $q = g \circ q$.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? In what form do you expect $\Gamma$ to be given to you?

Comment: @LeeMosher uhm, maybe via a generating set.

Comment: Even in the case of $U$ equal to the complement to a finite subset $A$, an "explicit" computation of $\Gamma$ in terms of $A$ is a notorious open problem, going back to Poincare (the problem of "accessory parameters").

Comment: @MoisheCohen That would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even in the case of $U$ equal to the complement to a finite subset $A$, an "explicit" computation of $\Gamma$ in terms of $A$ is a notorious open problem, going back to Poincare (the problem of "accessory parameters"). See for instance [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-313-02/S0002-9947-1989-0958896-0/S0002-9947-1989-0958896-0.pdf) for some background and references:

I.Kra, Accessory parameters for punctured spheres, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 313 (1989), 589-617.

In order to appreciate complexity of the question, consider reading [this](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Mazur.pdf) wonderful little paper by Barry Mazur:

Number theory as gadfly, Amer. Math. Monthly 98 (1991), no. 7, 593–610.

where he explains a relation of the uniformization problem for punctured tori to the Shimura-Taniyama Conjecture in number theory (proof of which made Andrew Wiles quite famous few yers later).