Explicit description of Fuchsian group for hyperbolic surfaces of finite type
Let $S_g$ be a Riemann surface with genus $g>1$. Uniformization theorem says the universal covering of $S_g$ is the upper half plan $\mathbb{H}$ and $S_g$ is conformal equivalent to $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$. Here $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{H}$, i.e. $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.
In this case, generators of $\Gamma$ can be written explicitly. In fact, we can represent $S_g$ by a $4g$-polygon $P$ whose edges are $a_1,b_1,a_1^{-1},b_1^{-1},\dots,a_2,b_2,a_2^{-1},b_2^{-1},\dots,a_g,b_g,a_g^{-1},b_g^{-1}$. Here $a_i^{-1},b_i^{-1}, i=1,\dots,g$ means they will be glued to $a_i,b_i,i=1,\dots,g$ respectively. Lift $P$ to a hyperbolic polygon $P'$ in $\mathbb{H}$ whose edges are geodesics in $\mathbb{H}$ named $a_1',b_1',a_1^{'-1},b_1^{'-1},\dots,a_2',b_2',a_2^{'-1},b_2^{'-1},\dots,a_g',b_g',a_g^{'-1},b_g^{'-1}$. Define maps $\alpha_i$ to be the auotomorphism mapping $a_i'$ to $a_i^{'-1}, i=1,\dots,g$ and define maps $\beta_i$ to be the auotomorphism mapping $b_i'$ to $b_i^{'-1}, i=1,\dots,g$. Then the Fuchsian group has representation
$$
\Gamma=<\alpha_i,\beta_i,i=1,\dots,g|\prod_{i=1}^g[\alpha_i,\beta_i]=1>.
$$
For a Riemann surface $S_{g,n}$ of genus $g$ and $n$ punctured points which satisfies $2g-2+n>0$. Its fundamental group has a representation
$$
\pi_1(S_{g,n})=<a_1,b_1,\dots,a_g,b_g, \gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n|\prod_{i=1}^g[a_i,b_i]\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\gamma_j=1>.
$$
Here $a_i,b_i,\gamma_j$ are simple closed curves on $S_{g,n}$. Thus from uniformization theorem, the Fuchsian group for $S_{g,n}$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(S_{g,n})$, it's actually a free group with $2g+n-1$ generators.
Question: can we find a explicit form of generators of Fuchsian group of punctured Riemann surface like in closed surface? Or is there any other way to explicitly write it?

Do you mean, $S$ with a given complex structure or just a topological surface?

@Moishe Kohan: With a given complex structure/hyperbolic structure.

Then it is hopeless: This is harder than the accessory parameters problem which is open since Poincare.

@Moishe Kohan：For Riemann surface of finite type, we can only find the explicit form of elements in Fuchsian group in the case of compact Riemann surface?

Not at all......

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610198/how-to-find-the-fuschian-group-associated-with-a-region-of-the-complex-plane/2611397#2611397

@Moishe Kohan: Thank you very much! One more question, can we find a description of fundament domian for punctured Riemann surface?

I do not understand the question.
